# TypeError: Cannot read property 'todos' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Hello I am new in React and trying to display the array called Todo that I have created in state, However, I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'todos' of undefined". Can you please tell me where I have done wrong?

Here is my code

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Todo from "./components/Todo.js";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

function App() {
  React.state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Take out the Trash",
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Imma out of stock..crystal meth",
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "google interview...",
        completed: false
      }
    ]
  };

  console.log(React.state.todos);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Todo todos={React.state.todos} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Todo.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

function Todo() {

  return React.props.todos.map((todo) => (
    <h3>{todo.title}</h3>
  ));

}

export default Todo;
```

Here is the error

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `useState` hook for state management and get the props from the function arguments. I have never seen something like this before. Following will work:

```js
const todos = React.useState([ ... ])
```

```js
function Todo(props) {

  return props.todos.map((todo) => (
    <h3>{todo.title}</h3>
  ));

}
```

If you are not familiar with React, read the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

> First of all, you can use `functional component` and `class componet`.
> And use react with component side `props` and `state` not in React library ( I mean `React.state` or `React.props` is impossible use case

### Answer

Welcome to react world! At the terms of react there is `Component`.
So you can basically make Component like this

```js
const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  return (<div> {props.title} </div>
}
```

```js
class SomeComponent extends Component {
   state = {
     someState: ...
   }
   render(){
     return(
       <div> {this.state.somestate} </div>
     )
   }
}
```

And when use `state` or `props` you can it from `this.state` or `this.state`(In class component) and `props` parameter (In functional component).

### Code

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Todo from "./components/Todo.js";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

class App extends Component {
 state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Take out the Trash",
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Imma out of stock..crystal meth",
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "google interview...",
        completed: false
      }
    ]
  }
render() {
   return (
      <div className="App">
       <Todo todos={this.state.todos} />
      </div>
   );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Todo.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

function Todo(props) {

  return props.todos.map((todo) => (
    <h3>{todo.title}</h3>
  ));

}

export default Todo;
```

### ETC

If you are beginner of programmer. It is a little bit curios about that concept. So I thinks it is helpful to some video lecture! thx have good night

Comment: This is not an answer. Simply posting a working version will not make him understand his mistakes

Comment: I write answer form of TLDR, Answer, Code ! but many people want to know direct answer ! I'm sorry about post answer firstly :(